# How do I implement the AuthGuard in the auto_route package with bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, router, bloc, flutter-bloc

Example AuthGuard from documentation

```
class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {                
 @override                
 void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) {                
 // the navigation is paused until resolver.next() is called with either                 
 // true to resume/continue navigation or false to abort navigation                
     if(authenticated){                
       // if user is authenticated we continue                
        resolver.next(true);                
      }else{                
         // we redirect the user to our login page                
         router.push(LoginRoute(onResult: (success){                
                // if success == true the navigation will be resumed                
                // else it will be aborted                
               resolver.next(success);                
          }));                
         }                    
     }                
}
```

Tried to use BlocListener

```
  BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is Authenticated) {
          AutoRouter.of(context).navigate(
            state.user.userType == UserType.master
                ? const MasterHomeRoute()
                : const ClientHomeRoute(),
          );
        } else {
          AutoRouter.of(context).navigate(const StartRoute());
        }
      },
    );
```

Also tried to use BlocProvider
`BlocProvider.of<AuthWatcherCubit>(router.navigatorKey.currentContext!).state`
but currentContext was null

Also tried to use another AuthGuard object
`extends AutoRedirectGuard`